# React Native multiple switches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

On React-Native, I'm trying to create a screen with multiple switch components, with the possibility of selecting only one at once. When the component loads, only the first switch in on. if you click on it, it turns to off, but if you turn on another one, all the others turn to off.

I'm not sure I have the right approach here, as I'm confused about how to use the component state to do this.

In JS, I would do something like a function that turns all switch to off, but turn on the clicked one, but I don't understand how to this with state.

thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, View, Switch } from 'react-native'

class switchScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      trueSwitchIsOn: true,
      falseSwitchIsOn: false
    }
  }

  switch = (value) => {
    this.setState({ falseSwitchIsOn: value, trueSwitchIsOn: !value })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switch}
          value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn}
        />
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switch}
          value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn}
        />
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switch}
          value={this.state.falseSwitchIsOn}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a more optimal solution would minimize the amount of state, and possibility of inconsistent data. Using one state variable to keep track of which switch is active (if any) can solve your problem pretty easily.

```
import React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, View, Switch } from 'react-native'

class switchScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeSwitch: null,
    }
  }

  // A simple toggle method that takes a switch number
  // And toggles it between on / off
  toggleSwitch = (switchNumber) => {
    this.setState({
      activeSwitch: switchNumber === this.state.activeSwitch ? null : switchNumber
    })
  };

  // 
  switchOne = (value) => { this.toggleSwitch(1) };
  switchTwo = (value) => { this.toggleSwitch(2) };
  switchThree = (value) => { this.toggleSwitch(3) };

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switchOne}
          value={this.state.activeSwitch === 1}
        />
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switchTwo}
          value={this.state.activeSwitch === 2}
        />
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.switchThree}
          value={this.state.activeSwitch === 3}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { ScrollView, Text, View, Switch } from 'react-native'

    class switchScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          switchone:false,
          switchtwo:false,
          switchthree:false,

        }
      }

      switchOne = (value) => {
        this.setState({ switchone: !value,
         switchtwo:false,switchthree:false,
         })
      }
 switchTwo = (value) => {
        this.setState({ switchtwo: !value,
         switchone:false,switchthree:false,
         })
      }
 switchThree = (value) => {
        this.setState({ switchtree: !value,
         switchone:false,switchtwo:false,
         })
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <View>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this.switchOne}
              value={this.state.switchone}
            />
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this.switchTwo}
              value={this.state.switchtwo}
            />
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this.switchThree}
              value={this.state.switchthree}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: If simple as this, I don't think anyone will ask. What if switch toggle in FlatList or in .map(function(){}) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below, you can keep array of switch states, in the example its an associative key, but you can change according to your need, with multi level switch states. (pardon the code formatting but it give you the idea)

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  switchStates: {
    companyName: true
  }
}
}

toggle(item, index) {
const switchStates = this.state.switchStates;
switchStates[index] = !switchStates[index];
console.log(switchStates);
this.setState({ switchStates });}
```

render switch

```
<Switch
    onValueChange={isSwitchOn =>
    this.toggle({ isSwitchOn }, "companyName")
    }
    value={this.state.switchStates.companyName}
/>
```